# Store objShell.run in variable

Tags: windows, vbscript, file-permissions

I am trying to store the output from a objShell.run and then display it out.

```
On Error Resume Next 
Set objShell = CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
strPermissionsDirValue = ""
strPermissionsDirValue = objShell.run ("cacls C:\SQL2008")
WScript.Echo VBTab & strPermissionsDirValue
strPermissionsDirValue = ""
```

When I execute the above I get 0.

The output should be
    C:\SQL2008 CREATOR OWNER:(OI)(CI)(IO)F
    NT AUTHORITY\SYSTEM:(OI)(CI)F
    BUILTIN\Administrators:(OI)(CI)F

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The WScript.Shell object will only return numbers, based on exit status of the application you launched.

One way would be to dump the output to a temp file. Change this line..

```
strPermissionsDirValue = objShell.run ("cacls C:\SQL2008")
```

To this..

```
objShell.run "cmd /k cacls C:\SQL2008 > temp.txt"
```

Then, just read that temp file and in this case, process each line of the cacls output.

```
Set objFSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")   
Set objInputFile = objFSO.OpenTextFile("temp.txt", 1)

Do While objInputFile.AtEndOfStream = False
  strLine = objInputFile.ReadLine      
Loop
```

Comment: Thanks. Decided to go with

    Set DirPermissions = objShell.Exec("%COMSPEC% /c cacls C:\SQL2008") 
    Do While DirPermissions.Status = 0 : WScript.Sleep 100 : Loop
    DirPermissionsFolder = DirPermissions.StdOut.ReadAll
    WScript.Echo DirPermissionsFolder